# Properties and objects regarding 3D Models in PowerPoint not showing up in the references of my application

Tags: vba, visual-studio, powerpoint

I'm working on a program that uses VBA scripts to check if people perform certain tasks in various Microsoft 365 applications, and some of those tasks include playing around with 3D Models (i.e. rotating them to a certain view).  The 3D models load into the application with everything else as they should, but the scripts I've written to verify if the user did anything with them do not work, and it returns an error stating that "Model3D is not a property of ShapeRange", when the exact same scripts work when used in my local PowerPoint application via macros:

```
Try
Dim rcount As Integer
With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(3).Model3D
   If .RotationX = 90 And _
            .RotationY = 300 And _
            .RotationZ = 270 Then
                Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
End With

Catch ex As Exception
   Return False
End Try
```

It appears the properties related to 3D models are not appearing in my references along with the rest of the PowerPoint objects, and I am unsure how to update the library to include these properties I need, or where I can find the dll file that can replace my current one.

Comment: You mention vba scripts, but the example you show (as a working example? not clear)  is not VBA.  A simplified version of your example does indeed work in VBA, but it's not clear what your problem code is written in. Also, you mention your "local version of PowerPoint" ... is the problem with some other non-local version or a different version on another system or ???

Comment: The problem code is an C# .net application that is used for teaching MS Office products. Students are given tasks and we use VBA scripts to verify/grade said tasks. The C# app uses scriptwrappers to run the VBA evaluation scripts and errors out when trying to run the above script however it runs just fine within the VBA editor in powerpoint. I inherited the program so I am not sure if I am looking in the right place, but I am thinking I need to update the object library as I cannot find the Model3D reference in Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll

Comment: If the C# app vs VBA version are running on different versions of Office, that could explain the problem but it sounds as though this is all happening on the same computer. Can you use COM to drive the process rather than interop? That'd give you direct access to the object model presented by PowerPoint (ie, same as in VBA) rather than the interop library's interpretation of the PPT OM, which I'm thinking might be out of date and not include the 3D features.  Take all of that with a grain of salt, however; I'm a VBClassic/VBA user, not familiar with .NET